# Is it possible to improve stats beyond what is shown?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do items in Binding of Isaac affect stats that are at max?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/do-items-in-binding-of-isaac-affect-stats-that-are-at-max)

Stats include something like 6 or 7 bars. I'd like to know if they can be improved past where it shows as fully upgraded.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the following question gives the answer to your own: [Do items in Binding of Isaac affect stats that are at max?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/do-items-in-binding-of-isaac-affect-stats-that-are-at-max)